# Symfony PdoSessionHandler not working as expected with PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, symfony, session

Im trying to move php sessions from files to database. Following this: [pdo_session_storage](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) I set up symfony as following:

config.yml:

```
session:
    handler_id:  session.handler.pdo
```

services.yml:

```
session.handler.pdo:
    class:  Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    arguments:
        - "pgsql:host=%database_host_access%;port=%database_port_access%;dbname=%database_name_access%"
        - { db_username: %database_user_access%, db_password: %database_password_access% }
```

The database is correctly seen and for each session a row is created in table: `sessions`.

The problem is: every time I reload a page the sessions attributes get lost. It seems like data are written from zero instead of being appended to the existing attributes.

With some debugging I found out that `NativeSessionStorage->loadSession()` load data from `$_SESSION` which is empty so `SessionHandlerProxy->write()` writes data with empty attributes.

NativeSessionStorage::loadSession():

```
protected function loadSession(array &$session = null)
{
    if (null === $session) {
        $session = &$_SESSION;
    }

    $bags = array_merge($this->bags, array($this->metadataBag));

    foreach ($bags as $bag) {
        $key = $bag->getStorageKey();
        $session[$key] = isset($session[$key]) ? $session[$key] : array();
        $bag->initialize($session[$key]);
    }

    $this->started = true;
    $this->closed = false;
}
```

Where `&$_SESSION;` is always empty.

This behavior is not present if I use `mysql` as `session.handler.pdo` argument or let php manages sessions via files.

I can't find resources about this topic that in my opinion is not a minor problem, did someone have some suggestion?

Im using Postgres version 9.4.1.0 and Symfony version 2.6.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem: PostgreSql version 9.0 changes the default bytea output in `hex` format but Symfony handles resources in `escape`.

A temporary solution is: `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET bytea_output = 'escape';`

Here the github issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14569

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I couldn’t figure out, why my stuff was working on dev, but not on production. Adding the above line in dev resulted in `Migration ... was executed but did not result in any SQL statements.`. I deployed with that migration anyway, and the production Postgres apparently had it in hex, because that line DID result in the SQL statement in production and now it works!! I work with Postgres 9.5.6 in dev, 9.6.3 in production, so I didn't think it would have been different. Production was AWS ElasticBeanstalk with RDS Postgres.

Comment: this is still an issue with Symfony 4.2 and AWS Psql 9.6.9

Comment: this is still an issue with Symfony 5.1.6 and PostgreSQL 12.4. Thanks for the fix